# How To Get The Closest Point To Lots Of Lines?

Tags: limits

I need a point that is closest to a number of lines. Similar to https://discourse.mcneel.com/t/point-closest-to-n-infinite-lines/35409/18 and [closest point to infinite line](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2843491/closest-point-to-infinite-line) but a logic approach and not a brute force one. (A way to find that works without guessing.) The answer would preferably work with multiple dimensions like regression. I have tried finding the points of intersection of each lines, then getting the average $x, y$. I think this has $O(n^2)$ in 2D and $O(n^d)$ where $d$ is the number of dimensions, where I would prefer less exponential time complexity. Any help?

Comment: What do mean by the closest point?  Are you trying to minimize the sum of the distances, the sum of the squares of the distances, the maximum distance, or something else?

Comment: I am trying to minimize the sum of distances.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Considering the distance squared due to it's algebraic formulation simplicity and calling the lines as

$$
\mathbb{l}_i\to p = p_i+\lambda_i \vec v_i,\ \ i = 1,\cdots , n
$$

and also calling $p_0 = (x_0,y_0,z_0)$ the sought point, we have to determine the minimum for

$$
F(\lambda, p_0) =\sum_{i=1}^n ||p_i+\lambda_i\vec v_i - p_0||^2
$$

Here $p_i,\vec v_i$ are known, and $\lambda = (\lambda_1,\cdots,\lambda_n)$

As

$$
F(\lambda, p_0) = \sum_{i=1}^n (p_i-p_0)\cdot(p_i-p_0)+2\lambda_i (p_i-p_0)\cdot \vec v_i + \lambda_i^2\vec v_i\cdot\vec v_i
$$

In order to obtain the minimum, the stationary conditions are given by

$$
0=\nabla F =\cases{\frac{\partial F}{\partial \lambda_i}\\ \frac{\partial F}{\partial p_0}} =  \cases{
\vec v_i\cdot(p_i-p_0)+\lambda_i||\vec v_i||^2 = 0\\
\sum_{i=1}^n p_0-p_i-\lambda_i\vec v_i = 0
}
$$

Those last conditions form a linear system to solve with $n+3$ equations and $n+3$ unknowns. Note that $\sum_{i=1}^n p_0-p_i-\lambda_i\vec v_i = 0$ are three conditions.

NOTE

$$
p_0 = \frac 1n\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i\vec v_i + p_i\right)
$$

Comment: What exactly does "stationary condition" mean?

Comment: I think it means that it will be always true.

Comment: @Cesareo can you please explain to me what 0− and ⃗ means? How can you subtract two points and a function? What function then does lambda-i stand for? (Sorry, I don't know mathjax) What does Hint mean? Does it mean you will give me the path to the answer but not the answer?

Comment: @JohnHao Please. See now some additional explanations included. Try to solve for $n = 2$ which is not so complex.

Comment: Still, what does 0− and ⃗ signify?

Comment: A line $i$ can be defined by giving an application point $p_i$ a gradient vector $\vec v_i$ and a real parameter $\lambda_i \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: You are minimizing the sum of the squares of the distances, whereas the OP wants to minimize the sum of the distances.   These are not at all the same thing.

Comment: I still do not understand how that would work. For me, it seems that a gradient vector would have no use in construction a line because there is only one variable to be changed and taking the directional derivative of that is just the gradient of the line, that combined with an application point would give me the line. At the same time, what is the real parameter and what does it do? Is the answer supposing lines of finite length and not lines of infinite length?

Comment: Please. Take some basic analytic geometry notions as for instance parametric line representation.  See for instance http://mathonline.wikidot.com/parametric-equations-of-lines

Comment: Still, what does the application point do? I get the ⃗ part as a parametric equation of a line through the origin, but shouldn't you add to it a vector and not a point?